# Recibir respuesta en php y definirla en android studio

Tags: php

Estoy creando un sistema de registro y login, pero quiero comprobar si ya hay un usuario con ese nombre, para ello, lo estoy comprobando con esto: 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE username = '$username'`, 
de forma que si la respuesta es 1, no me permita crear un nuevo usuario con ese nombre, y si es 0, que me permita acceder y crearlo, este es mi código php que tengo por el momento:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "---";
$password = "---";
$db = "---";

//connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

$username = $_POST["username"];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `login` WHERE username = '$username'";

?>
```

Gracias.

**EDIT:**
Me gustaría poder recibir la respuesta en forma de string o en json, ya que lo voy a usar en andorid studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu código le falta la ejecución de la consulta SQL, la extracción del resultado y el envío de éste al cliente.

Además, tu código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string).

La ejecución de la consulta se realiza con una llamada a [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) o bien [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) si usas consultas preparadas.

La obtención del resultado se puede realizar mediante [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc).

Por último, para enviar los datos en JSON hay que fijar la cabecera necesaria (`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`) y usar la función [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) para obtener el valor correctamente generado como valor JSON (aunque al ser numérico éste será el número tal cual).

He aquí tu código finalizado con las modificaciones sugeridas:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "---";
$password = "---";
$db = "---";

//connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

/* Escapamos correctamente el usuario recibido por POST
    para evitar inyección SQL */
$username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);

/* Agregamos un alias al COUNT(*) para poder acceder a él fácilmente */
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) numero FROM `login` WHERE username = '$username'";

/* Hacemos efectiva la consulta */
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);

/* Obtenemos el primer y único registro */
$registro = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

/* Enviamos al cliente el resultado (numérico) codificado en JSON
    (que será únicamente el número sin más) */
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($registro['numero']);
```

NOTA: Este código no gestiona errores SQL o cualquier otro error que ocurra durante las llamadas a las funciones `mysqli`. Debe comprobarse el resultado de llamar a cada una de ellas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: De nada, un placer. Ten en cuenta lo que puse en la PD. No puedo hacer gestión de errores porque el resultado es un número único. Lo ideal sería enviar un JSON con una estructura del tipo: `{error: false, resultado: 0}` para indicar que no hubo error y que el resultado es `0` o bien `{error: true, mensaje: "Hubo un error SQL tal y cual"}` para indicar una condición de error.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
$result=$link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `login` WHERE username LIKE '$username'");
foreach($result as $rows){}

if($rows[0]>0){
   echo "1"; //Existe
}else{
   echo "0"; //No existe
}
```

Saludos :)